# passing data from jquery to label

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am not so familar with angular, I want to use multiple select dropdown in my asp.net website. with grouping. from the example here : http://www.jqueryrain.com/?pYw7weSs

```
 <select class="selectpicker" multiple  data-max-options="2">
<optgroup label="Condiments" data-max-options="2">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Breads" data-max-options="2">
  <option>Plain</option>
  <option>Steamed</option>
  <option>Toasted</option>
</optgroup>
```

how can i pass the selected values from the dropdown to aspx label.

Thanks for advise

Comment: Why you try to swim in the deep water if you can not even know swimming ?

Comment: because it's there :)

Comment: Look, make your user interface and your full program with simple normal drop down lists... later when you finish with all that, you may find the time to make it better.... you must know that usually this kind of controls don't even work on ie8 and down..., need a lot of checks to fully work with all system... and probably some updates in the future... So if you don't know how to do it... drop it.